# How to extract value from an object and also an array to form another array?

Tags: reactjs

How do I extract "category" from data and use it as the key for the new output array that includes "name" field from listData array

```
 const data = {
    "32": {
        "id": 32,
        "category": "Grocery Items",
    }, I 
     "33": {
        "id": 33,
        "category": "Household Items",
    }, 
}
```

This is the listData array and I would need to extract the data from list.

```
const listData = [
{
    "data": {
        "list": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "category_id": 32,
                "title": "Eggs",
                "category": "Grocery Items"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "category_id": 32,
                "title": "Bacon",
                "category": "Grocery Items"
            }
         ]
     }
}
]
```

Sample Output:

It contains the category from data as the key and data from list array.

```
const output = {
    "Grocery Items": [
      {
            "id": 1,
            "category": "Grocery Items",
            "name": "Eggs",
      },
      {
            "id": 2,
            "category": "Grocery Items",
            "name": "Bacon",
      },
      ]
}
```

I tried this but did not give the correct structure

```
    const output = Object.values(data).map((acc, { title, id }) => {
                let filteredList = [];
                listData.forEach((element) => {
                    console.log(element.data.list)
                    filteredList = element.data.list
                        .filter((item) => item.title === title)
                });

                if (filteredList.length) {
                    acc[title] = filteredList;
                }

                return acc;
            }, {});
```

Comment: what did you tried ?

Comment: I added the solution i tried in the question @zb

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use `reduce` method. Ad [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) says:

> The reduce() method executes a user-supplied "reducer" callback
> function on each element of the array, in order, passing in the return
> value from the calculation on the preceding element. The final result
> of running the reducer across all elements of the array is a single
> value.

So code would look like this:

```
let obj = array.reduce((acc, cur)  => {
  acc[cur.category_id] = {id: cur.category_id, category: cur.category };
  return acc;
}, {});
```

An example can be seen here:

```js
const array = [
  {
      "id": 1,
      "category_id": 32,
      "title": "Eggs",
      "category": "Grocery Items"
  },
  {
      "id": 2,
      "category_id": 33,
      "title": "Bacon",
      "category": "Grocery Items 33"
  }
]


let obj = array.reduce((acc, cur)  => {
  acc[cur.category_id] = {id: cur.category_id, category: cur.category };
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(obj)
```